# How deep is soil?

Tags: soil, soil-science

I am curious of the lower boundary of soil. Soil is formed after going through complex processes and it has been through coevolution with living organisms. According to the [USDA](https://www.nrcs.usda.gov/wps/portal/nrcs/detail/soils/edu/?cid=nrcs142p2_054280), for soil classification, the lower boundary of soil is arbitrarily set at 2 m. So, this is obviously not the actual depth. Yost and Hartemink (2020), in a review article mentioned soil depth/thickness:

> A general term for the vertical dimension of the soil. Some authors consider it includes only the solum, some others include the solum plus the C and the G horizons (whether they represent or
> not the soil parent material), and some others consider it as equivalent to the root-restricting
> depth.

Considering C horizon while calculating the soil depth is also stated in a research by Richter and Markewitz(1995). They have mentioned varying depth of soils from 20 m to 100 m depending on spatial variations in climatic features. So, till which distance from our earth's surface is soil? Is there any standard depth of soil?

**References:**

1. Yost, J.L., Hartemink, A.E. (2020). *How deep is the soil studied – an analysis of four soil science journals*. Plant Soil 452, 5–18. https://doi.org/10.1007/s11104-020-04550-z
2. Richter, D., & Markewitz, D. (1995). *How Deep Is Soil?* BioScience, 45(9), 600-609. doi:10.2307/1312764

Comment: Soil has a specific meaning/composition that is not dependent on "depth".  Soil depth can vary based on many factors.  Here's a nice dataset that shows soil depth maps.  https://daac.ornl.gov/SOILS/guides/Global_Soil_Regolith_Sediment.html

Comment: So, there is no way we can say that soil has a standard depth. It will vary from region to region.

Answer (score 2):

"Soil" is a loose amalgam of various earthen materials and organic detritus, thus conditions that create soil in various regions; soil "Thickness" depends on where soil ends and regolith (solid rock) begin